# Launch application shortcut from activity

Tags: android, shortcut

How to launch any applications shortcut (not an application) from my app code programmatically.

And is it possible to launch it every 3 minutes using alarmmanager.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the package name in the intent then startactivity(intent).

PS: Please dont play this prank as it can hamper (LOL)